# Equivalent or alternative method for RAISE EXCEPTION statement for function in LANGUAGE sql?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Is there an equivalent (or workaround) for the RAISE EXCEPTION statement for the function written below in `LANGUAGE sql`?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_interpolation (p_yearinteger integer, 
p_admin_id integer, p_crop_id integer, p_cropparameter integer)

RETURNS TABLE (value double precision, remark text)

AS $$

WITH

yearvalues AS (SELECT yearinteger, value FROM cropvalues WHERE crops_id = 
p_crop_id AND admin_id = p_admin_id AND parameter_id = p_cropparameter),
```

I need the function to abort and to RETURN an error message if the arguments entered into the function do not exist.  e.g. `IF parameter_id != p_cropparameter THEN RAISE EXCEPTION ‘invalid cropparameter’ END IF`

Comment: is your function language plpgsql?

Comment: No, SQL doesn't have exceptions. You need to re-write it using PL/pgSQL

Comment: SQL certainly does have exceptions - as in, situations which abort processing. Just try dividing a number by zero!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just define a trivial wrapper function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION raise_exception(text) RETURNS text AS $$
BEGIN
    RAISE EXCEPTION '%',$1;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

then use `CASE`:

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN parameter_id != p_cropparameter 
           THEN raise_exception("blah") 
         ELSE parameter_id 
       END;
```

This only works if the `CASE` otherwise returns `text` though, e.g. if `parameter_id` is integer you get:

```
regress=> SELECT CASE WHEN 1 = 2 THEN raise_exception('blah') ELSE 1 END;
ERROR:  CASE types integer and text cannot be matched
LINE 1: SELECT CASE WHEN 1 = 2 THEN raise_exception('blah') ELSE 1 E...
```

You can work around this with a hack using polymorphic functions. Define:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION raise_exception(anyelement, text) RETURNS anyelement AS $$
BEGIN
    RAISE EXCEPTION '%',$2;
    RETURN $1;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

then pass a fake value of the case type to it so PostgreSQL type-matches it correctly, e.g.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 1 = 1 THEN raise_exception(0, 'blah') ELSE 1 END;
```

or

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 1 = 1 THEN raise_exception(NULL::integer, 'blah') ELSE 1 END;
```

All seem too hard? That's because really, this sort of thing is usually just better done in PL/PgSQL.

Comment: I asked a similar question (now linked to this one) but the reason I want to use SQL for the function definition is to make it possible for the SQL function to be inlined. But your suggestion to use SQL CASE with a plpgsql wrapper function for the exception is perfectly obvious in hindsight :). Thanks!

Comment: @DoctorEval A Pl/PgSQL wrapper will prevent inlining of the function, and thus prevent clause pulldown/pushup and other optimisation across the boundary between the function and the outer query. FYI.

Comment: Thanks Craig. Does this mean that including a plpgsql function call in a `CASE` ... `WHEN` will prevent the statement containing the `CASE` from being inlined? Or does it just mean that the plpgsql function call itself won't be inlined. The latter I can deal with.